# Need to perform something on the time of block creation

Tags: nodeos

Is there any way to include a script or anything else for achieving something on the time of creation of a block?

for example, A simple token transfer on the time of block creation.

Comment: off-chain script can monitor the blockchain and propagate transaction when triggered

Comment: will demux work for the same?

Comment: Are you wanting to execute a transaction on the creation of a new block?  Or are you wanting to execute something outside of the blockchain?

Comment: I want to execute a transaction on the creation of a new block